# How should I handle the retrieval of a recently inserted record ID so that it may be inserted into another table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have a Vendor object within my View Model.  When I insert this vendor record into the database, I want to retrieve the ID of this Vendor because it will be used as a foreign key on another table immediately after (in a different sproc).  I'm attempting to do this with `test` as the ID I need to retrieve.  The following code doesn't work because `proc_amcInsertApplicationServerRelationship` expects an integer, but `test` is of type of `Object Parameter`.

I guess my questions are:

Am I approaching this correctly?  If not, what would be a better approach?  Also, based on my current approach, is there something simple I'm overlooking that I could do to get this to work?  Here's my code (sorry if I'm not providing enough detail):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ApplicationViewModel applicationViewModel)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            ObjectParameter test = new ObjectParameter("ID", typeof (int));
            var vendorID = db.proc_amcInsertNewVendor(applicationViewModel.Vendor.Company, applicationViewModel.Vendor.StreetAddress, applicationViewModel.Vendor.SecondaryStreetAddress,
                applicationViewModel.Vendor.City, applicationViewModel.Vendor.State, applicationViewModel.Vendor.ZipCode, applicationViewModel.Vendor.PhoneNumber,
                applicationViewModel.Vendor.Website, test);

            foreach (var serverID in applicationViewModel.ServerIDs)
            {
                db.proc_amcInsertApplicationServerRelationship(test, serverID);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Per Request, here's my stored procedure.

```
@Company varchar(100)
,@StreetAddress varchar(100)
,@SecondaryStreetAddress varchar(50)
,@City varchar(50)
,@State varchar(50)
,@ZipCode varchar(10)
,@PhoneNumber varchar(15)
,@Website varchar(200)

,@ID int = NULL OUT

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
INSERT INTO [dbo].[amc_Vendors]
(
 [Company]
,[StreetAddress]
,[SecondaryStreetAddress]
,[City]
,[State]
,[ZipCode]
,[PhoneNumber]
,[Website]
)
VALUES
(
 @Company
,@StreetAddress
,@SecondaryStreetAddress
,@City
,@State
,@ZipCode
,@PhoneNumber
,@Website
)

SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
GO
```

Comment: Can you Provide your Stored Proc Also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your SP after insert statement. Use

```
Select @@IDENTITY As ReturnedId
```

In your service code, do:

```
int Id=db.proc_amcInsertApplicationServerRelationship(serverId).FirstOrDefault().ReturnedId;
```

Use this Id for your further processing.

Comment: I would just like to note that depending on the usage of the database, `@@IDENTITY` may be unreliable. If you are running a insert, delete, or update as the last line, it would be more reliable to use a [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause.

Answer (score 1):

There is solution to this but you need to make sure for the followings:
-What you can try with your current code is return Identity of recently added Items with `@@Identity` in SQL procedure and get the same from command as return value or as output parameter.

- Use the returned value and sent the same in next operation.

But as far as my expertise says this would be not good option. Since you are having dependencies for Query execution, You need to implement Transaction as well.

you can handle them at both database and Application level

Use Single SP to insert records in both table with Transaction or
Use Transaction class at Application level in C#

Hope these would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Do Following:

In Your SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.YourSPName 
     @Param1 varchar(156),
    @Id Int OUTPUT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT @Id = @@IDENTITY
```

In your C# code:

```
 var outputParameter = new ObjectParameter("Id", typeof(int));

 context.YourSPName("ParamValue", outputParameter);

 Console.WriteLine(outputParameter.Value);
```